# How to find an example of $G$ amenable such that $G^\mathbb{N}$ isn't amenable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, amenability

What is an example of an amenable group $G$ such that $G^\mathbb{N}$ isn't amenable?

My thoughts: Consider for example $G=\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\ |\ a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a\neq 0\}$, which is amenable as it is solvable. Now if we could prove that for every $n$ there are $g_n,h_n\in G$ such that every non trivial word in $g_n,h_n$ (viewed as if in the free group) which is equal in $G$ to the identity must have length at least $n$, then $(g_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(h_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ would generate a free group in $G^\mathbb{N}$. Is it possible to find such $g_n,h_n$? If not, how could we proceed?

Comment: Do you know that every free group is residually finite?

Comment: Yes; does that help?

Comment: Yes, it does help.

Comment: How so? I know that I can embedd $F_2$ in the product of all its finite quotients, but this isn't always the same group...

Comment: Related (but distinct) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825062/amenability-of-countable-product-of-a-finite-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: First, find an amenable group $G$ which contains (isomorphic copies of) all finite groups.

Comment: Thanks I think I get it now! We could take $S_\infty$, the directed union of all finite permutation groups. The final detail would then be to prove that $F_2$ contains only counatbly many normal subgroups of finite index; is this true?

Comment: @RedundantAunt: It suffices to know that there are only finitely many homomorphisms to each $S_n$. But you do not even need this.